# Install lxml on mac 10.8.3

Tags: python, lxml

I have a bulk standard Mac 10.8.3 install, which is using:
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin.

How do I go about installing lxml, what are the exact procedures, as I have tried loads of suggestion on here, but can't seem to get it installed.
Whats the correct way using a bulk standard OSX 10.8.3?

Kind regards.

Comment: Have you tried the instructions at http://lxml.de/installation.html?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install Lxml on Mac os x 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548011/cannot-install-lxml-on-mac-os-x-10-9)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.
Install the xcode command line tools from here http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/06/install-gcc-without-xcode-in-mac-os-x/. Then open terminal and type `sudo pip install lxml`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Just FYI, you can download the command line tools separately from connect.apple.com; I do this since I am not a ios developer and can do without xcode. Also, the first thing I install is [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) which makes this stuff easier.

Comment: Sorry, just saw your post after already finding it and editing my post, cheers for the info though.