# Error on trying to install lxml on Mac (Mavericks) for use in Django 1.5

Tags: django, macos, python-2.7

```
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/private/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -flat_namespace

clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'

clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-flat_namespace'

In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:16:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:33:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found


error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: +1 same situation here. After installing Xcode, I still get these same errors when doing pip install lxml.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth making sure you have Xcode command line tools installed as well (`xcode-select --install`), per [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548011/cannot-install-lxml-on-mac-os-x-10-9).

In some cases, there are command-line tools you can't use until a sudoer has signed Apple's terms of service within Xcode, so make sure you do that too (I don' think you can do the former without doing the latter anyway).

Hope that helps.