# Installing command line tools Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, command-line, xcode5, osx-mavericks, command-line-tool

I have tried and tried (looked at many headings for this) and I still don't have an answer to my problem. I am trying to install the Pebble SDK 1.12 and install command line tools of Xcode 5.

Everytime I try xcode-select --install    in terminal  I get "Can't install software because it is not currently available in the Software Update server"

I have tried to reinstall Xcode and that didn't work. 
When I got to Xcode-preferences-downloads there isn't a section for the command line tools.

I have also tried installing them from the Developer site but to no avail. The download looks correct and then I go to Xcode to see the preferences and the command line tools aren't listed.

Anything you all can suggest?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using xcode-select --install in Terminal and choose install tools

Comment: I get "xcode-select: Error: unknown command option '--install'."

Answer (score 2):

On OS X 10.9, the `Command Line Tools` component no longer appears in the `Preferences` pane for Xcode 5, unlike on OS X 10.8. Also, the `not currently available` message appears to be a bug in OS X 10.9 when the currently installed `Command Line Tools` are already up-to-date. If you have a populated `/usr/include` directory and `/usr/bin/cc --version` gives you something, you're probably fine.

Comment: I a line in the terminal that said 
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2
Thread model: posix

Comment: Great.  So, if, for example, `ls -l /usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h` shows an existing file, you should be all set.

Comment: To verify you have the tools, you can check the location where they live:
   ll /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/
If you're upgrading, go ahead and verify their versions: most have a -v / --version argument.