# Installing lxml OSX Mavericks 10.9.2

Tags: python, macos, lxml, osx-mavericks, cc

I am trying to install lxml on 10.9.2 Mavericks and i used all the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548011/cannot-install-lxml-on-mac-os-x-10-9) before but i seem to get a different error, the argument '-mno-fused-madd' is unknown, i believe it just triggered a warning back then, but now it throws an error here's the log

```
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/Users/workspace/mybooktype/build/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w -flat_namespace

clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

**UPDATE 1**
i was originally trying to install the django app [booktype](https://github.com/sourcefabric/Booktype) so following the instructions i tried first

```
pip install lxml --install-option="--with-xml2-config=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.8.0/bin/xml2-config"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem had nothing to do with the C compiler, it was in the python version used on the machine, apparently there was a conflict in python versions, a new clean installation of python solved the problem, and the `.bash_profile`. then we used the original command

```
pip install lxml
```

and it was successfully installed

Comment: Use HomeBrew to install a fresh python

Answer (score 1):

you should install or upgrade command line tool for xcode. please try command in terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: I've already tried it but it didn't work, the problem was in the python version i used i am now on 2.7.6. Thanks for help