# ImportError: No module named lxml on Mac

Tags: python, macos, lxml

I am having a problem running a Python script and it is showing this message:

```
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

I suppose I have to install somewhat called lxml but I am really newbie to Python and I don't really have too much idea on that.

I think I have two versions of Python installed on my Mac from what I have read in other threads, but I am not sure.

How can I solve this issue?

Python Version: 2.7.6

Mac OS X 10.9.2

Comment: Finally I solved my problem using this command:
`STATIC_DEPS=true pip install lxml`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install Lxml on Mac os x 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548011/cannot-install-lxml-on-mac-os-x-10-9)

Answer (score 10):

I've installed recently using `pip`, but before it would all work, I needed to issue the following command as instructed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19604913/748858):

```
xcode-select --install
```

If you don't have `pip`, you can get it from `easy_install`.  If I recall correctly, the full sequence of commands should be something like this (assuming you already have gotten Xcode):

```
sudo easy_install pip
xcode-select --install
sudo pip install lxml
```

Comment: I am trying to install the command line developer tools via you first command but it says that the software can not be installed because it is not available in the upgrade's server. Also, I am trying to run the first line of your second code and it says that python version 2.7.6 can't run usr/bin/easy_install and it gives me three alternatives (python 2.5, 2.6 and 2.7).

Comment: It works for me, thank you very mach. Just would like to add t hat I did only the following steps:

`xcode-select --install`
`sudo pip install lxml`

Answer (score 4):

The answer of your question is here: http://lxml.de/installation.html#installation

Go to the MacOS section and follow the instructions :-)

Comment: I have tried to use this command: port install py25-lxml but it says the next: port:command not found

Comment: You have to install MacPort, it's not something available by default on MacOS. Otherwise, you can build it yourself using the Building lxml on MacOS-X section.