# make: *** No rule to make target 'qt5py3'. Stop

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm working on a machine learning assignment. By the when I was trying to install the following file

```
brew install qt qt5
brew install libxml2
make qt5py3
python labelImg.py
python  labelImg.py [IMAGE_PATH] [PRE-DEFINED CLASS FILE]
```

at make qt5py3 the output from terminal is make: *** No rule to make target 'qt5py3'.  Stop

I'm using OsX high sierra with default terminal
Does anyone know just what's happened?

Comment: Where did this file come from?

Comment: @John Gordon https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg this one

Comment: Are you running this file in the same directory as the `Makefile`?

Comment: @JohnGordon which directory should I put their folder in ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To get the labelImg package (from the link you gave) working on OSX High Sierra, I needed to do the following.

First installed the missing lxml dependency using the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674730/importerror-no-module-named-lxml-on-mac)

Also

```
brew install qt qt5
brew install libxml2
brew install pyqt5
```

After installing pyqt5, ensure that pyrcc5 can be run from the command line.

Download and unzip the labelImg .zip file from the link, and **cd into the unzipped folder**. Then

```
make qt5py3
```

When trying to run, I found it necessary to simplify the libs/usty.py file to remove the PyQt4 dependency. I just changed it to:

```
import sys
def ustr(x):
    return x
```

At this point I can run the program with

```
python labelImg.py
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: What did you say in this? Please explain for the understanding. But it really worked for me.

Comment: AS Mackay, I did what you say, but when a run "pytohn labelImg.py" appears this "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "labelImg.py", line 24, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtGui"
How to install PyQt4.QrGui?

Answer (score 10):

For me, I have occurred the same problem (MacOS version 10.13.4 and python 3.7)  and solved using below steps.

1. Unzip the labelImg downloaded from [here](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg), `cd labelImg-master`
2. `brew install qt qt5
   brew install libxml2
   brew install pyqt5`
3. `make qt5py3`
4. `python3 labelImg.py`

Answer (score 2):

you should download the project from github and enter the folder where file "makefile" is in,

then run make qt5py3

Comment: I get this error pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rafikgouiaa/anaconda3/bin/pyrcc5", line 7, in <module>
    from PyQt5.pyrcc_main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt5/pyrcc_main.py", line 21, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION_STR, QDir, QFile
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyClass_Type
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so
  Expected in: flat namespace

make: *** [qt5py3] Error 1

Answer (score 1):

on Macbook

open terminal at folder "labelimg"
run:
`make qt5py3`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31202391)

Answer (score 0):

Came across this post (and maybe 30 others) while trying to install labelImg.

This gentleman's solution (from the beginning) finally allowed me to get started:

First, install Mini Conda (https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/macos.html), and open a new terminal window.

```
cd labelImg  
conda create -n py2 python=2.7  
source activate py2  
conda install pyqt=4  
conda install libxml2  
conda install lxml  
make qt4py2  
python labelImg.py
```

https://gist.github.com/plopd/487f2caf2f983abc990987b97a8a734b

Answer (score 0):

> brew install qt qt5

downloaded and extracted zip file from
https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg

> make qt5py3
> after running this command i got an error stating "No module found pyqt5";

> pip install pyqt5

run

> python labelImg.py