# Python3, lxml and "Symbol not found: _lzma_auto_decoder" on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, lxml, homebrew

I have installed python 3 using homebrew and afterwards installed pip3 and lxml.

The following line

> > > from lxml import entree

leads to the following error:

```
$ python3
Python 3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 01:12:57) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from lxml import etree
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-  packages/lxml/etree.so, 2): Symbol not found: _lzma_auto_decoder
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
>>> exit();
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Same problem for me with Mavericks, MacOS X 10.9.4, Darwin Kernel Version 13.3.0; python3.4 installed through homebrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted all versions of python from

```
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
```

afterwards I have reinstalled python 3 using brew and recreated the symlinks using

```
     brew link --overwrite python3
```

Comment: Well.. Your solution removes python2.x (python2.7 these days) right? It's not an option for many people (me included). Do you have a better way?

Comment: I did something similar and screwed up my system :'( . If you still want to test this, please make a backup before deleting.

Answer (score 2):

Facing a similar problem:

`ImportError: dlopen(.../python3.11/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_exsltDateXpathCtxtRegister'`

The only workaround I found is to uninstall lxml and to reinstall with conda:

```
$ conda activate my_env
$ pip uninstall lxml
$ conda install -c conda-forge lxml
```

Answer (score 1):

Deleting lxml and re-installing lxml a SECOND time worked for me (weird, not happy with this solution):

```
pip3.4 uninstall lxml
pip3.4 install lxml
```

pip3 complains about lxml being already installed, remove manually the install files with a command like:

```
rm -fr /private/var/folders/dj/saljfdsf12_sd7s89dfg9080000rb/T/pip_build_user/lxml
```

Then again:

```
pip3.4 install lxml
```

And it worked. I couldn't reproduce the original error message to find root cause of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Homebrew and have `xz` installed, the following should work:

```
STATIC_DEPS=true CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include/lzma pip install -U lxml
```

Otherwise set CFLAGS to the place where your lzma headers are located.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue,

What I did:

First, I ensured I did not have the ports `py27-xml2`, `py27-xslt` or `py27-lxml` installed

```
sudo port installed | grep py27
```

I installed port `py27-pip` and checked that $PATH variable pointed it. Also installed `py27-setuptools`.

```
$  sudo port contents py27-pip | grep /pip$
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip

in ~/.bash_profile:
export PATH="/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"

$  which pip
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip
```

Then I installed `lxml` with easy_install which was located in the same directory than `pip`

```
STATIC_DEPS=true sudo easy_install-2.7 lxml
```

The building process was displaying:

```
$  STATIC_DEPS=true sudo easy_install-2.7 lxml
Searching for lxml
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/
Downloading 
....
Building without Cython.
Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.29
Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /Applications/MAMP/Library/  
....

        libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
```

I moved MAMP (seems to already come with those libs) at the end of $PATH, uninstalled `lxml` (displayed "Symbol not found: _lzma_auto_decoder" error) and repeated last command:

```
$ STATIC_DEPS=true sudo easy_install-2.7 -m "lxml==3.6.4"

in ~/.bash_profile:
export PATH="/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library"

$  source ~/.bash_profile

$  STATIC_DEPS=true sudo easy_install-2.7 lxml
```

This fixed the error either inside or outside `virtualenv`

```
$  python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jun 29 2016, 12:46:54)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from lxml import etree
>>>
```