# Python: error when installing lxml on OS X

Tags: python-2.7, pip

For whatever I'm installing with pip, I got this:

```
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/kn/mmhj7w0n54s4b2jr08sx46kr0000gn/T/pip_build_youweizhu/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/kn/mmhj7w0n54s4b2jr08sx46kr0000gn/T/pip-0wnEw6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/kn/mmhj7w0n54s4b2jr08sx46kr0000gn/T/pip_build_youweizhu/lxml
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/youweizhu/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

For example:

```
$ pip install lxml
```

I got

```
Downloading/unpacking lxml
  Downloading lxml-3.4.1.tar.gz (3.5MB): 3.5MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/kn/mmhj7w0n54s4b2jr08sx46kr0000gn/T/pip_build_youweizhu/lxml/setup.py) egg_info for package lxml
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.4.1.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.py'
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.4.1.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/private/var/folders/kn/mmhj7w0n54s4b2jr08sx46kr0000gn/T/pip_build_youweizhu/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w -flat_namespace
    In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:239:
    /private/var/folders/kn/mmhj7w0n54s4b2jr08sx46kr0000gn/T/pip_build_youweizhu/lxml/src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:14:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found
    #include "libxml/xmlversion.h"
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/kn/mmhj7w0n54s4b2jr08sx46kr0000gn/T/pip_build_youweizhu/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/kn/mmhj7w0n54s4b2jr08sx46kr0000gn/T/pip-0wnEw6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'

  warnings.warn(msg)

Building lxml version 3.4.1.

Building without Cython.

Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/html

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron

copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

running build_ext

building 'lxml.etree' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/src

creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/src/lxml

cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/private/var/folders/kn/mmhj7w0n54s4b2jr08sx46kr0000gn/T/pip_build_youweizhu/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w -flat_namespace

In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:239:

/private/var/folders/kn/mmhj7w0n54s4b2jr08sx46kr0000gn/T/pip_build_youweizhu/lxml/src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:14:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found

#include "libxml/xmlversion.h"

         ^

1 error generated.

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/kn/mmhj7w0n54s4b2jr08sx46kr0000gn/T/pip_build_youweizhu/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/kn/mmhj7w0n54s4b2jr08sx46kr0000gn/T/pip-0wnEw6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/kn/mmhj7w0n54s4b2jr08sx46kr0000gn/T/pip_build_youweizhu/lxml
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/youweizhu/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

I'm crying...

Answer (score 3):

try this command:

```
STATIC_DEPS=true pip install lxml
```

from doc:
http://lxml.de/installation.html#using-lxml-with-python-libxml2

or Try:

```
sudo ln -s  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/libxml
```

Answer (score 2):

Andre Augusto pointed out

> If you want to use lxml together with the official libxml2 Python
>   bindings (maybe because one of your dependencies uses it), you must
>   build lxml statically. Otherwise, the two packages will interfere in
>   places where the libxml2 library requires global configuration, which
>   can have any kind of effect from disappearing functionality to crashes
>   in either of the two.
>
> To get a static build, either pass the --static-deps option to the
>   setup.py script, or run pip with the STATIC_DEPS or STATICBUILD
>   environment variable set to true, i.e.
>
> STATIC_DEPS=true pip install lxml
>
> The STATICBUILD environment variable is handled equivalently to the
>   STATIC_DEPS variable, but is used by some other extension packages,
>   too.

from the lxml docs here..
http://lxml.de/installation.html#using-lxml-with-python-libxml2

his original post is here:
[Cannot install Lxml on Mac os x 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548011/cannot-install-lxml-on-mac-os-x-10-9)
There's some other ios related fixes there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a line that works

```
STATIC_DEPS=true LIBXML2_VERSION=2.9.2 pip install lxml
```

I had the same problem myself, and I found this answer at http://louistiao.me/posts/installing-lxml-on-mac-osx-1011-inside-a-virtualenv-with-pip/

I also raise a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/1546046 and I recommend you to add a comment there, otherwise it will be ignored and the lxml user experience will continue to suck.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by following command

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --use-pep517 lxml --install-option="--static-deps=true" --install-option="--libxml2-version=2.11.4"
```