# Error when installing Scrapy on Mac 10.10.2

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, pycharm

I am trying to install Scrapy on my Mac 10.10.2 via the PyCharm IDE.
However, I get this error

> 0:430: execution error: DEPRECATION: --no-install, --no-download, --build, and --no-clean are deprecated.  See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/906.

PyCharm advises to install it in the terminal, but that gives me the following errors. How can I solve this?

> Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
>       requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
>       requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 671, in install
>       self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 901, in move_wheel_files
>       pycompile=self.pycompile,
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 215, in move_wheel_files
>       clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 205, in clobber
>       os.makedirs(destdir)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
>       mkdir(name, mode)
>   OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy'
>
> Storing debug log for failure in
>   /var/folders/1x/0m8r2wt57mb0y4xy8k5swhkc0000gn/T/tmpaER1Oo

EDIT:
The solution for me was to update the command line tool for XCode as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548011/cannot-install-lxml-on-mac-os-x-10-9)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running 

`sudo pip install scrapy?`

Comment: Running sudo pip install scrapy gave less errors, but still one error remains with regards to the lxml module.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on lxml, so you also need to install lxml, then scrapy