# Error when importing python-docx?

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml, python-docx

When I do `import docx` with the `python-docx` module, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Userpath/script.py", line 19, in <module>
    import docx
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docx/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from docx.api import Document  # noqa
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docx/api.py", line 14, in <module>
    from docx.package import Package
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docx/package.py", line 11, in <module>
    from docx.opc.package import OpcPackage
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docx/opc/package.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .part import PartFactory
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docx/opc/part.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .oxml import serialize_part_xml
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docx/opc/oxml.py", line 12, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so, 2): Library not loaded: libxslt.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
  Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath libxslt.1.dylib in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so with restricted binary
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with your `lxml` installation.

I expect you get the same answer in Python when you type in the line:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
```

Which means it's not related to `python-docx`, it's just trying to load a package that's not (or not properly) installed.

Best bet is to search on 'windows install lxml' and learn what you can, but the quick fix might be to uninstall whatever `lxml` you have and reinstall it from scratch using a binary distribution from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

Comment: Yes, the same error occurs through the command line, but even after uninstalling and reinstalling lxml, the issue persists. I'm on Mac 10.11, for reference.

Comment: Could be not having libxml2 and libxslt libraries installed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26544099/1902513

Comment: This, too, did not solve the issue :(. Both of those libraries installed successfully and without errors, but the original error associated with lxml has not changed.

Comment: Hmm, it seems this is a new problem. There are some indications of what it might be if you search on 'lxml unsafe use of relative rpath libxslt.1.dylib'. Apparently some new security measures on OS X 10.7 or so. This GitHub comment indicates adding a symlink might work if you can interpolate from the mysql case: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/646#issuecomment-140141504

Comment: Also you should probably make sure the `lxml` guys know about this. The long-term fix will be a change they make in their code I believe. I've added the `lxml` tag to your question. One other direction you could pursue is running in a virtualenv. If you're using the default OS X install of Python, that's in a protected area (directory owned by root) and could be contributing. Another option would be installing the homebrew Python so it's in a local (to you) directory rather than `/Library/...`.

Comment: My stopgap solution has been to just use a different computer, because I need this to work for my job, but I would obviously prefer if this would work on my primary system. Is there any other information I can gather that would help to solve this issue, or otherwise aid the lxml devs in fixing it?

Comment: Well, if I were them, I'd like to know whether installing in a non-root-owned Python installation worked. I expect it will. That would be the Python you installed with homebrew, for example. It's wise practice not to fool around with the default OS X Python installation because it's used by Mac system maintenance scripts, and because it's owned by `root` you have to use `sudo` to add or remove packages (in fact, using `sudo -H pip install lxml` might actually work, but I wouldn't recommend it :). I'd either try a non-root installation or a virtualenv and include the results you found.