# Python XML parser to find an SVG group and remove classes from child paths, polygons, and circles

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Goal:**  Within SVG g id="RoundShapes" for all path, poly, rect, polygon, ellipse, and circle tags: remove class.  Leave class in subgroups (g tags) within the RoundShapes group.

I'm able to pull up an element tree; but I don't know python well enough to use the XPATHS or to remove the classes, and apply the removed classes to the svg_text string which is a larger SVG.

Combining a few references, this is what I have started.

Any help in achieving the goal would be appreciated.

I previously attempted this with re.sub and Regex but was directed by several people to try XML parsing instead...

Code:

```
def remove_RD_group_classes(svg_text):
    """
    Within SVG <g id="RoundShapes"> for all path, poly, rect, polygon, ellipse, and circle tags, remove class.  Leave class in subgroup g tags.
    """
    
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    
    root = ET.fromstring(svg_text)
    
    roundshapes = root.findall("//*[@id='RoundShapes']")
    
    for classes_removed in roundshapes.xpath('//*[@class]'):
    classes_removed.attrib.pop('class')
```

Here is the svg_text that is loaded as an example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Shapes" viewBox="0 0 612 792">
    <defs>
        <style>.cls-1{fill:#730e31;}.cls-1,.cls-11,.cls-12,.cls-2,.cls-4,.cls-5,.cls-6,.cls-7,.cls-8,.cls-9{stroke:#231f20;stroke-miterlimit:10;}.cls-2{fill:#2c318e;}.cls-3{fill:#231f20;}.cls-4{fill:#e60680;}.cls-5{fill:#ee2742;}.cls-6{fill:#2a3e98;}.cls-7{fill:#00aeef;}.cls-8{fill:#62449b;}.cls-9{fill:#e6a923;}.cls-10{fill:#ed1c24;}.cls-11{fill:#a8cf38;}.cls-12{fill:none;}</style>
    </defs>
    <g id="PolyShapes">
        <polygon class="cls-1" points="331.2 451.55 190.02 502.69 75.14 406 101.45 258.17 242.62 207.03 357.5 303.72 331.2 451.55"/>
        <polygon class="cls-2" points="487.4 188.74 395.4 243.94 301.6 191.88 299.79 84.61 391.79 29.41 485.59 81.48 487.4 188.74"/>
        <g id="OtherShapesAndLines">
            <g id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1">
                <path class="cls-3" d="M143.08,124.94c-4.72,3.18-9.54,6.24-14.18,9.54-4.31,3.08-7.27,7.23-5.43,12.72,1.41,4.23,5.1,7.91,7.82,11.36,3.07,3.9,6.24,7.73,9.46,11.51,12.79,15,26.48,29.14,39.1,44.26,12.13,14.52,23.41,30.23,30.75,47.79,3.3,7.89,8.23,19.14,4.57,27.67-1.71,4-5.57,6.62-7.3,10.7a18.18,18.18,0,0,0,.19,14.11c4.08,10.18,13.55,14.28,20.85,21.6,6.41,6.42,5,17.7-4.44,20.43-7.41,2.13-4.26,13.72,3.19,11.57A24.26,24.26,0,0,0,244.32,351c2.33-9-.91-17.46-7.44-23.75-5.59-5.4-18-10.69-18.4-19.64-.21-4.12,4.43-7.12,6.37-10.42a27.62,27.62,0,0,0,3.42-14.39c-.19-9.77-4-19.28-7.91-28.1a162.5,162.5,0,0,0-14.2-25.41c-11.07-16.4-24.31-31.19-37.55-45.85-7.39-8.19-14.82-16.36-21.91-24.82q-2.77-3.3-5.47-6.67c-1.57-2-3.3-5.25-5.26-6.82-1.53-1.22-.58-1.62-1-.24.3-1,3.7-2.5,4.72-3.19l9.45-6.36c6.38-4.29.38-14.69-6-10.36Z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="DefinedPolyShapes">
        <polygon id="PinkStar" class="cls-4" points="300.86 650.54 248.69 604.37 181.09 621.17 208.88 557.29 172.01 498.19 241.35 504.88 286.17 451.55 301.23 519.57 365.8 545.71 305.77 581.05 300.86 650.54"/>
    </g>
    <g id="RoundShapes">
        <g id="ReddishRound">
            <ellipse class="cls-5" cx="402.27" cy="406.98" rx="25.62" ry="44.57"/>
        </g>
        <g id="BluishRound" class="bluishround">
            <ellipse class="cls-6" cx="268.91" cy="468.5" rx="39.15" ry="35.95"/>
            <g id="BluishRoundOvals">
                <ellipse class="cls-7" cx="-5.99" cy="192.88" rx="55.37" ry="28.93"/>
                <ellipse class="cls-7" cx="57.64" cy="239.16" rx="26.45" ry="128.1"/>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g id="OtherRound">
            <circle class="cls-8" cx="72.52" cy="255.69" r="58.68"/>
            <ellipse class="cls-9" cx="393.6" cy="198.25" rx="50.83" ry="34.3"/>
            <g id="free_draw" data-name="free draw">
                <path class="cls-3" d="M264.19,356.46a78.69,78.69,0,0,0-16.12,17.84c-4,6.06-8.49,13.77-8.61,21.24-.32,19.43,29,16.81,41.19,13.29,8.39-2.41,14-6.67,15.38-15.65a54.7,54.7,0,0,0-1.71-24.81c-2.13-6.82-5.55-15.45-12.62-18.44a11.93,11.93,0,0,0-10.67.49c-3.15,1.89-4.11,5.48-6.83,7.66-6,4.84,2.52,13.28,8.49,8.49,1.64-1.32,2.41-3.05,3.75-4.57a15.28,15.28,0,0,1,.89-1.37l.13.56c.64.18,1.29,1.56,1.62,2.06a38.53,38.53,0,0,1,5.09,14c.84,4.73,1.21,10.52-.15,15.18-1.47,5-9.15,5.73-13.69,6.32a43,43,0,0,1-16.3-.7c-2.37-.64-2.85-1.2-2.4-3.72a24.4,24.4,0,0,1,2.4-6.28A68.61,68.61,0,0,1,272.68,365c6-4.87-2.54-13.32-8.49-8.49Z"/>
                <path class="cls-3" d="M364.05,442.28c-12.83,7-14.81,23.26-6,34.37,9,11.36,25.48,13.4,38.74,9.81,13.95-3.78,25.66-14.94,27.85-29.54,2-13.28-5.21-27.24-18.08-32-8.49-3.13-15.93-.08-23.17,4.46l-24.89,15.65c-6.52,4.11-.5,14.49,6.06,10.37L383,443.81c4.78-3,11.28-9,17.33-8.18,12.27,1.59,15,17.39,10.11,26.47-5.8,10.81-19.31,15.62-31.05,13.57-5.45-.95-10.9-3.67-13.53-8.77-2.83-5.49-1.19-11.28,4.25-14.26,6.77-3.71.72-14.08-6.06-10.36Z"/>
                <path class="cls-3" d="M289.19,194c-19.47,6.15-41.16,15-45.88,37.27-4.21,19.92,7.41,39.36,28.09,42.33,45.88,6.61,63.66-55.14,39.64-86.47-13.28-17.32-40.76-21.21-54.58-2.33-4.57,6.24,5.84,12.24,10.36,6.06,8.44-11.53,26-6.92,33.87,2.43C310.37,204.69,312,222.2,308,236.2S292.9,262,277.55,262.05c-14.3.09-24.51-10.76-23.06-25.11,1.95-19.44,21.91-26.36,37.89-31.41,7.34-2.31,4.21-13.9-3.19-11.57Z"/>
                <path class="cls-3" d="M186.17,35.2c-7.1,11.86-15.15,33.11-1.69,43.48,12,9.26,31.73,8.1,44.26.62s20.37-22.29,18-36.9a32,32,0,0,0-29.4-26.88c-19.17-1.22-33.68,13-44.31,27.14-4.65,6.17,5.77,12.16,10.36,6.06,8-10.62,19.4-22.46,33.95-21.2,13.23,1.14,20.62,15.15,16.77,27.21C229.86,68,215.78,74.51,202.6,72.87c-6.52-.82-13.64-2.88-13.28-10.6.34-7.38,3.47-14.77,7.21-21,4-6.64-6.39-12.68-10.36-6Z"/>
                <path class="cls-3" d="M111.11,184.61c-1.86,16.63.44,35.24,13.61,47,12.52,11.19,29.66,11.15,43.22,1.69,13.79-9.61,23.27-25.33,26.94-41.6,3.23-14.31,2.69-32.46-9.79-42.39-7.73-6.15-18-7-27.56-6.45a88.59,88.59,0,0,0-31,7.74c-7,3.12-1,13.47,6.06,10.36a72.66,72.66,0,0,1,28.53-6.23c7.57-.08,15.59.92,19.92,7.89,7.89,12.7,2.27,31.54-4.53,43.42-6.92,12.09-21.61,27.39-37,21.06-16.54-6.77-18.08-27.3-16.38-42.5.85-7.67-11.15-7.61-12,0Z"/>
                <path class="cls-3" d="M195.49,299l-1.67,3.3a6.43,6.43,0,0,0-.6,4.63,6,6,0,0,0,11,1.43l1.66-3.3a6.36,6.36,0,0,0,.6-4.62,6,6,0,0,0-7.38-4.2,6,6,0,0,0-3.58,2.76Z"/>
                <path class="cls-3" d="M181.56,380.67a132.43,132.43,0,0,0,57.94,45.09c2.94,1.18,6.69-1.31,7.38-4.19,7.86-33.07-19.48-61.28-47.13-74.39-12.09-5.73-29-11.51-40.08-.47-5.29,5.29-7.37,13-9.09,20.08a129.69,129.69,0,0,0-3.51,27.75c-.17,7.72,11.83,7.72,12,0a113.55,113.55,0,0,1,2.26-20.88c1.15-5.55,2.25-12.79,5.87-17.39,7.2-9.15,23.29-.58,31,3.54,20.66,11.08,43.26,32.75,37.12,58.57l7.38-4.19a117.78,117.78,0,0,1-50.77-39.57c-4.5-6.18-14.92-.2-10.36,6.05Z"/>
                <path class="cls-10" d="M129,503.44c-11.5,8.36-23.83,18-26.94,32.74-2.82,13.4,3.23,26.6,16,32.14s29,1.33,37.86-9.41,7.54-26.77-.69-37.54c-4.63-6-15-.08-10.36,6.06,5.09,6.66,7.7,16.37,2,23.57s-17.17,10.12-25.39,5.72-9.88-13.67-6.54-21.83c3.75-9.18,12.33-15.45,20.08-21.09,6.19-4.5.21-14.91-6-10.36Z"/>
                <path class="cls-10" d="M428.44,303.58a90.76,90.76,0,0,0-2.24,45.25c1.18,5.74,3.38,13,10.36,13.53,6.4.48,10.78-7,13.69-11.66,7.23-11.64,10.29-25.27,11.9-38.72,1.34-11.2,2.27-29.18-9.52-35.67-7.86-4.32-14.41,2.91-19.27,8.29A102.14,102.14,0,0,0,419,305c-3.64,6.8,6.71,12.87,10.36,6.06a90.13,90.13,0,0,1,10.72-16c1.56-1.82,3.79-5.23,5.94-6.32,2.67-1.35.24-1.83,2.26,0,.84.76,1.21,2.53,1.52,3.54,3.21,10.37.27,23.76-2.38,34a67.89,67.89,0,0,1-6,15.65c-1.38,2.52-3.54,4.79-4.8,7.32l-1,1.22q4.39,2.3,3.34.09c.18-.92-.8-3-1-4A78.21,78.21,0,0,1,440,306.77c2.29-7.4-9.29-10.56-11.57-3.19Z"/>
                <g id="Layer_15" data-name="Layer 15">
                    <path class="cls-10" d="M184.51,283.15c-4.06,9.29-10.66,30.15,3.21,34.5,11.9,3.73,27.61.9,36.64-7.79,8.15-7.84,12.85-20.36,12.67-31.61-.08-5.35-1.36-10.9-4.82-15.11-4.42-5.38-10.88-6.45-17.5-6.54-7.72-.11-7.73,11.89,0,12,3.55,0,7.15-.1,9,3.36,1.44,2.62,1.45,6,1.21,8.94a34.16,34.16,0,0,1-7.11,18.39c-5,6.12-12.2,7.71-19.83,7.53-1.09,0-5.7.35-6.43-.51-.28-.35,0-3,.09-3.68a38.66,38.66,0,0,1,3.2-13.42c3.07-7-7.26-13.12-10.36-6.06Z"/>
                    <path class="cls-10" d="M373,184.76a181.71,181.71,0,0,0-48.85,23.55c-6.38,4.39-13.43,9.17-16.71,16.48a15.7,15.7,0,0,0,5.35,19.67c6.24,4.47,14.65,5.46,22.07,6.27A103.48,103.48,0,0,0,405.26,232c14.53-10.69,25.67-29.4,12.83-45.91-4.74-6.09-13.17,2.46-8.49,8.48,4.92,6.33,1.32,15.22-3.25,20.54-5.23,6.08-12.46,10.56-19.52,14.19a91.75,91.75,0,0,1-45.54,9.9A82.2,82.2,0,0,1,330,238c-3.35-.61-8-1.14-10.67-3.51-5.6-4.95,5.84-12.32,9.39-14.82a170.39,170.39,0,0,1,47.43-23.35c7.35-2.3,4.21-13.89-3.19-11.57Z"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <ellipse class="cls-11" cx="297.73" cy="273.45" rx="24.38" ry="51.65"/>
        </g>
        <circle class="cls-12" cx="327.59" cy="388.85" r="21.59"/>
    </g>
    <g id="SquareShapes">
        <rect class="cls-12" x="153.51" y="85.44" width="152.49" height="81.82"/>
        <rect class="cls-4" x="419.63" y="543.29" width="92.56" height="92.56"/>
        <rect class="cls-12" x="376.65" y="232.55" width="71.9" height="71.9"/>
        <g id="Freedraw">
            <path class="cls-3" d="M481.63,222.69a393.26,393.26,0,0,0-79.93,13c-4.1,1.11-5.09,5.33-3.59,8.81l3,7,5.18-9a197.38,197.38,0,0,0-48.19,2c-6.06,1-15.28,1.36-19.43,6.55-4.62,5.78-.78,15,.66,21.39a530,530,0,0,0,29.48,90.88c1.56,3.67,7,3.63,9.42,1.22,10.22-10,28.28-7.18,41.19-6.48,16.29.88,32.81,2,48.87-1.68a84.91,84.91,0,0,0,22.59-9c6.31-3.55,12.82-7.08,13.78-14.91s.66-16.06.48-23.91a137.13,137.13,0,0,0-2.52-24.25c-3.34-16.28-15.7-33.93-9.81-50.81,2.56-7.3-9-10.44-11.57-3.19-5.1,14.6.8,29.06,5.66,42.83,5.45,15.47,6.54,31.05,6.22,47.35,0,2.91.84,8.47-.41,11.08-1.17,2.43-5.56,4.13-7.89,5.45a74.06,74.06,0,0,1-23.26,8.47c-16,2.9-32.51.91-48.59.21-15-.66-31.73-.93-43.22,10.31l9.42,1.22a513.83,513.83,0,0,1-25.9-77.94c-1.54-6.27-2.24-13.22-4.35-19.28.19-1.8-.06-2.31-.76-1.53-.77.55-.45.54,1,0a27.91,27.91,0,0,0,4.66-1q5.15-1.06,10.34-1.83a185.32,185.32,0,0,1,42.17-1.12c5.05.42,6.79-5.28,5.18-9l-3-7-3.58,8.82a377,377,0,0,1,76.74-12.56c7.67-.46,7.72-12.46,0-12Z"/>
            <path class="cls-3" d="M379,478q-45.24-6-90.89-7.77a6.06,6.06,0,0,0-6,6,242.4,242.4,0,0,1-6.66,66.39c-.71,2.91.91,6.83,4.19,7.38a79.76,79.76,0,0,0,23.84.73c7.61-1,14.62-3.39,21.93-5.57,15.6-4.63,30.64,1.7,46.4,1.21a6.08,6.08,0,0,0,6-6q-.74-26.67.69-53.32c.41-7.72-11.59-7.7-12,0q-1.42,26.64-.69,53.32l6-6c-15,.46-29.38-5.22-44.36-2.13-7.13,1.47-13.83,4.47-21,5.93a64.78,64.78,0,0,1-23.64.26l4.19,7.38a254.29,254.29,0,0,0,7.09-69.58l-6,6Q333.73,484,379,490c3.24.43,6-3.07,6-6,0-3.59-2.8-5.58-6-6Z"/>
        </g>
        <g id="BluishRectangles">
            <rect class="cls-7" x="111.36" y="345.77" width="50.23" height="50.23"/>
            <rect class="cls-7" x="353.51" y="239.16" width="50.23" height="50.23"/>
            <rect class="cls-7" x="478.31" y="370.88" width="50.23" height="50.23"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Here is expected output:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Shapes" viewBox="0 0 612 792">
    <defs>
        <style>.cls-1{fill:#730e31;}.cls-1,.cls-11,.cls-12,.cls-2,.cls-4,.cls-5,.cls-6,.cls-7,.cls-8,.cls-9{stroke:#231f20;stroke-miterlimit:10;}.cls-2{fill:#2c318e;}.cls-3{fill:#231f20;}.cls-4{fill:#e60680;}.cls-5{fill:#ee2742;}.cls-6{fill:#2a3e98;}.cls-7{fill:#00aeef;}.cls-8{fill:#62449b;}.cls-9{fill:#e6a923;}.cls-10{fill:#ed1c24;}.cls-11{fill:#a8cf38;}.cls-12{fill:none;}</style>
    </defs>
    <g id="PolyShapes">
        <polygon class="cls-1" points="331.2 451.55 190.02 502.69 75.14 406 101.45 258.17 242.62 207.03 357.5 303.72 331.2 451.55"/>
        <polygon class="cls-2" points="487.4 188.74 395.4 243.94 301.6 191.88 299.79 84.61 391.79 29.41 485.59 81.48 487.4 188.74"/>
        <g id="OtherShapesAndLines">
            <g id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1">
                <path class="cls-3" d="M143.08,124.94c-4.72,3.18-9.54,6.24-14.18,9.54-4.31,3.08-7.27,7.23-5.43,12.72,1.41,4.23,5.1,7.91,7.82,11.36,3.07,3.9,6.24,7.73,9.46,11.51,12.79,15,26.48,29.14,39.1,44.26,12.13,14.52,23.41,30.23,30.75,47.79,3.3,7.89,8.23,19.14,4.57,27.67-1.71,4-5.57,6.62-7.3,10.7a18.18,18.18,0,0,0,.19,14.11c4.08,10.18,13.55,14.28,20.85,21.6,6.41,6.42,5,17.7-4.44,20.43-7.41,2.13-4.26,13.72,3.19,11.57A24.26,24.26,0,0,0,244.32,351c2.33-9-.91-17.46-7.44-23.75-5.59-5.4-18-10.69-18.4-19.64-.21-4.12,4.43-7.12,6.37-10.42a27.62,27.62,0,0,0,3.42-14.39c-.19-9.77-4-19.28-7.91-28.1a162.5,162.5,0,0,0-14.2-25.41c-11.07-16.4-24.31-31.19-37.55-45.85-7.39-8.19-14.82-16.36-21.91-24.82q-2.77-3.3-5.47-6.67c-1.57-2-3.3-5.25-5.26-6.82-1.53-1.22-.58-1.62-1-.24.3-1,3.7-2.5,4.72-3.19l9.45-6.36c6.38-4.29.38-14.69-6-10.36Z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="DefinedPolyShapes">
        <polygon id="PinkStar" class="cls-4" points="300.86 650.54 248.69 604.37 181.09 621.17 208.88 557.29 172.01 498.19 241.35 504.88 286.17 451.55 301.23 519.57 365.8 545.71 305.77 581.05 300.86 650.54"/>
    </g>
    <g id="RoundShapes">
        <g id="ReddishRound">
            <ellipse cx="402.27" cy="406.98" rx="25.62" ry="44.57"/>
        </g>
        <g id="BluishRound" class="bluishround">
            <ellipse cx="268.91" cy="468.5" rx="39.15" ry="35.95"/>
            <g id="BluishRoundOvals">
                <ellipse cx="-5.99" cy="192.88" rx="55.37" ry="28.93"/>
                <ellipse cx="57.64" cy="239.16" rx="26.45" ry="128.1"/>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g id="OtherRound">
            <circle cx="72.52" cy="255.69" r="58.68"/>
            <ellipse cx="393.6" cy="198.25" rx="50.83" ry="34.3"/>
            <g id="free_draw" data-name="free draw">
                <path d="M264.19,356.46a78.69,78.69,0,0,0-16.12,17.84c-4,6.06-8.49,13.77-8.61,21.24-.32,19.43,29,16.81,41.19,13.29,8.39-2.41,14-6.67,15.38-15.65a54.7,54.7,0,0,0-1.71-24.81c-2.13-6.82-5.55-15.45-12.62-18.44a11.93,11.93,0,0,0-10.67.49c-3.15,1.89-4.11,5.48-6.83,7.66-6,4.84,2.52,13.28,8.49,8.49,1.64-1.32,2.41-3.05,3.75-4.57a15.28,15.28,0,0,1,.89-1.37l.13.56c.64.18,1.29,1.56,1.62,2.06a38.53,38.53,0,0,1,5.09,14c.84,4.73,1.21,10.52-.15,15.18-1.47,5-9.15,5.73-13.69,6.32a43,43,0,0,1-16.3-.7c-2.37-.64-2.85-1.2-2.4-3.72a24.4,24.4,0,0,1,2.4-6.28A68.61,68.61,0,0,1,272.68,365c6-4.87-2.54-13.32-8.49-8.49Z"/>
                <path  d="M364.05,442.28c-12.83,7-14.81,23.26-6,34.37,9,11.36,25.48,13.4,38.74,9.81,13.95-3.78,25.66-14.94,27.85-29.54,2-13.28-5.21-27.24-18.08-32-8.49-3.13-15.93-.08-23.17,4.46l-24.89,15.65c-6.52,4.11-.5,14.49,6.06,10.37L383,443.81c4.78-3,11.28-9,17.33-8.18,12.27,1.59,15,17.39,10.11,26.47-5.8,10.81-19.31,15.62-31.05,13.57-5.45-.95-10.9-3.67-13.53-8.77-2.83-5.49-1.19-11.28,4.25-14.26,6.77-3.71.72-14.08-6.06-10.36Z"/>
                <path  d="M289.19,194c-19.47,6.15-41.16,15-45.88,37.27-4.21,19.92,7.41,39.36,28.09,42.33,45.88,6.61,63.66-55.14,39.64-86.47-13.28-17.32-40.76-21.21-54.58-2.33-4.57,6.24,5.84,12.24,10.36,6.06,8.44-11.53,26-6.92,33.87,2.43C310.37,204.69,312,222.2,308,236.2S292.9,262,277.55,262.05c-14.3.09-24.51-10.76-23.06-25.11,1.95-19.44,21.91-26.36,37.89-31.41,7.34-2.31,4.21-13.9-3.19-11.57Z"/>
                <path d="M186.17,35.2c-7.1,11.86-15.15,33.11-1.69,43.48,12,9.26,31.73,8.1,44.26.62s20.37-22.29,18-36.9a32,32,0,0,0-29.4-26.88c-19.17-1.22-33.68,13-44.31,27.14-4.65,6.17,5.77,12.16,10.36,6.06,8-10.62,19.4-22.46,33.95-21.2,13.23,1.14,20.62,15.15,16.77,27.21C229.86,68,215.78,74.51,202.6,72.87c-6.52-.82-13.64-2.88-13.28-10.6.34-7.38,3.47-14.77,7.21-21,4-6.64-6.39-12.68-10.36-6Z"/>
                <path d="M111.11,184.61c-1.86,16.63.44,35.24,13.61,47,12.52,11.19,29.66,11.15,43.22,1.69,13.79-9.61,23.27-25.33,26.94-41.6,3.23-14.31,2.69-32.46-9.79-42.39-7.73-6.15-18-7-27.56-6.45a88.59,88.59,0,0,0-31,7.74c-7,3.12-1,13.47,6.06,10.36a72.66,72.66,0,0,1,28.53-6.23c7.57-.08,15.59.92,19.92,7.89,7.89,12.7,2.27,31.54-4.53,43.42-6.92,12.09-21.61,27.39-37,21.06-16.54-6.77-18.08-27.3-16.38-42.5.85-7.67-11.15-7.61-12,0Z"/>
                <path d="M195.49,299l-1.67,3.3a6.43,6.43,0,0,0-.6,4.63,6,6,0,0,0,11,1.43l1.66-3.3a6.36,6.36,0,0,0,.6-4.62,6,6,0,0,0-7.38-4.2,6,6,0,0,0-3.58,2.76Z"/>
                <path d="M181.56,380.67a132.43,132.43,0,0,0,57.94,45.09c2.94,1.18,6.69-1.31,7.38-4.19,7.86-33.07-19.48-61.28-47.13-74.39-12.09-5.73-29-11.51-40.08-.47-5.29,5.29-7.37,13-9.09,20.08a129.69,129.69,0,0,0-3.51,27.75c-.17,7.72,11.83,7.72,12,0a113.55,113.55,0,0,1,2.26-20.88c1.15-5.55,2.25-12.79,5.87-17.39,7.2-9.15,23.29-.58,31,3.54,20.66,11.08,43.26,32.75,37.12,58.57l7.38-4.19a117.78,117.78,0,0,1-50.77-39.57c-4.5-6.18-14.92-.2-10.36,6.05Z"/>
                <path d="M129,503.44c-11.5,8.36-23.83,18-26.94,32.74-2.82,13.4,3.23,26.6,16,32.14s29,1.33,37.86-9.41,7.54-26.77-.69-37.54c-4.63-6-15-.08-10.36,6.06,5.09,6.66,7.7,16.37,2,23.57s-17.17,10.12-25.39,5.72-9.88-13.67-6.54-21.83c3.75-9.18,12.33-15.45,20.08-21.09,6.19-4.5.21-14.91-6-10.36Z"/>
                <path d="M428.44,303.58a90.76,90.76,0,0,0-2.24,45.25c1.18,5.74,3.38,13,10.36,13.53,6.4.48,10.78-7,13.69-11.66,7.23-11.64,10.29-25.27,11.9-38.72,1.34-11.2,2.27-29.18-9.52-35.67-7.86-4.32-14.41,2.91-19.27,8.29A102.14,102.14,0,0,0,419,305c-3.64,6.8,6.71,12.87,10.36,6.06a90.13,90.13,0,0,1,10.72-16c1.56-1.82,3.79-5.23,5.94-6.32,2.67-1.35.24-1.83,2.26,0,.84.76,1.21,2.53,1.52,3.54,3.21,10.37.27,23.76-2.38,34a67.89,67.89,0,0,1-6,15.65c-1.38,2.52-3.54,4.79-4.8,7.32l-1,1.22q4.39,2.3,3.34.09c.18-.92-.8-3-1-4A78.21,78.21,0,0,1,440,306.77c2.29-7.4-9.29-10.56-11.57-3.19Z"/>
                <g id="Layer_15" data-name="Layer 15">
                    <path  d="M184.51,283.15c-4.06,9.29-10.66,30.15,3.21,34.5,11.9,3.73,27.61.9,36.64-7.79,8.15-7.84,12.85-20.36,12.67-31.61-.08-5.35-1.36-10.9-4.82-15.11-4.42-5.38-10.88-6.45-17.5-6.54-7.72-.11-7.73,11.89,0,12,3.55,0,7.15-.1,9,3.36,1.44,2.62,1.45,6,1.21,8.94a34.16,34.16,0,0,1-7.11,18.39c-5,6.12-12.2,7.71-19.83,7.53-1.09,0-5.7.35-6.43-.51-.28-.35,0-3,.09-3.68a38.66,38.66,0,0,1,3.2-13.42c3.07-7-7.26-13.12-10.36-6.06Z"/>
                    <path  d="M373,184.76a181.71,181.71,0,0,0-48.85,23.55c-6.38,4.39-13.43,9.17-16.71,16.48a15.7,15.7,0,0,0,5.35,19.67c6.24,4.47,14.65,5.46,22.07,6.27A103.48,103.48,0,0,0,405.26,232c14.53-10.69,25.67-29.4,12.83-45.91-4.74-6.09-13.17,2.46-8.49,8.48,4.92,6.33,1.32,15.22-3.25,20.54-5.23,6.08-12.46,10.56-19.52,14.19a91.75,91.75,0,0,1-45.54,9.9A82.2,82.2,0,0,1,330,238c-3.35-.61-8-1.14-10.67-3.51-5.6-4.95,5.84-12.32,9.39-14.82a170.39,170.39,0,0,1,47.43-23.35c7.35-2.3,4.21-13.89-3.19-11.57Z"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <ellipse cx="297.73" cy="273.45" rx="24.38" ry="51.65"/>
        </g>
        <circle cx="327.59" cy="388.85" r="21.59"/>
    </g>
    <g id="SquareShapes">
        <rect class="cls-12" x="153.51" y="85.44" width="152.49" height="81.82"/>
        <rect class="cls-4" x="419.63" y="543.29" width="92.56" height="92.56"/>
        <rect class="cls-12" x="376.65" y="232.55" width="71.9" height="71.9"/>
        <g id="Freedraw">
            <path class="cls-3" d="M481.63,222.69a393.26,393.26,0,0,0-79.93,13c-4.1,1.11-5.09,5.33-3.59,8.81l3,7,5.18-9a197.38,197.38,0,0,0-48.19,2c-6.06,1-15.28,1.36-19.43,6.55-4.62,5.78-.78,15,.66,21.39a530,530,0,0,0,29.48,90.88c1.56,3.67,7,3.63,9.42,1.22,10.22-10,28.28-7.18,41.19-6.48,16.29.88,32.81,2,48.87-1.68a84.91,84.91,0,0,0,22.59-9c6.31-3.55,12.82-7.08,13.78-14.91s.66-16.06.48-23.91a137.13,137.13,0,0,0-2.52-24.25c-3.34-16.28-15.7-33.93-9.81-50.81,2.56-7.3-9-10.44-11.57-3.19-5.1,14.6.8,29.06,5.66,42.83,5.45,15.47,6.54,31.05,6.22,47.35,0,2.91.84,8.47-.41,11.08-1.17,2.43-5.56,4.13-7.89,5.45a74.06,74.06,0,0,1-23.26,8.47c-16,2.9-32.51.91-48.59.21-15-.66-31.73-.93-43.22,10.31l9.42,1.22a513.83,513.83,0,0,1-25.9-77.94c-1.54-6.27-2.24-13.22-4.35-19.28.19-1.8-.06-2.31-.76-1.53-.77.55-.45.54,1,0a27.91,27.91,0,0,0,4.66-1q5.15-1.06,10.34-1.83a185.32,185.32,0,0,1,42.17-1.12c5.05.42,6.79-5.28,5.18-9l-3-7-3.58,8.82a377,377,0,0,1,76.74-12.56c7.67-.46,7.72-12.46,0-12Z"/>
            <path class="cls-3" d="M379,478q-45.24-6-90.89-7.77a6.06,6.06,0,0,0-6,6,242.4,242.4,0,0,1-6.66,66.39c-.71,2.91.91,6.83,4.19,7.38a79.76,79.76,0,0,0,23.84.73c7.61-1,14.62-3.39,21.93-5.57,15.6-4.63,30.64,1.7,46.4,1.21a6.08,6.08,0,0,0,6-6q-.74-26.67.69-53.32c.41-7.72-11.59-7.7-12,0q-1.42,26.64-.69,53.32l6-6c-15,.46-29.38-5.22-44.36-2.13-7.13,1.47-13.83,4.47-21,5.93a64.78,64.78,0,0,1-23.64.26l4.19,7.38a254.29,254.29,0,0,0,7.09-69.58l-6,6Q333.73,484,379,490c3.24.43,6-3.07,6-6,0-3.59-2.8-5.58-6-6Z"/>
        </g>
        <g id="BluishRectangles">
            <rect class="cls-7" x="111.36" y="345.77" width="50.23" height="50.23"/>
            <rect class="cls-7" x="353.51" y="239.16" width="50.23" height="50.23"/>
            <rect class="cls-7" x="478.31" y="370.88" width="50.23" height="50.23"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a short, representative sample of `svg_text` and the expected output from that sample?

Comment: @JackFleeting I did so above. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First, note that in your example, the element `<g>` which  has the attribute `id` with the `RoundShapes` attribute value, only has child tags `circle`, `ellipse` and `path`, but not poly, rect or polygon. So the answer will only relate to the first three; you'll have to modify it to fit your actual xml.

Second, I would use a more robust xml parser, namely lxml.  So:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.XML(svg_text)

target_tags = ['circle', 'ellipse','path']

#you have to declare namespaces
ns = {'xx': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'}

for target in target_tags:
    exp = f'//xx:g[@id="RoundShapes"]//xx:{target}'
    to_modify = doc.xpath(exp,namespaces=ns)
    for mod in to_modify:
        del mod.attrib['class']
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

The output should be your expected output.

Comment: Thanks Jack - I really didn't understand what you meant by lxml.  I tried to install it on my Mac (OS Monterey) can't seem to get it to work. I reviewed several sources including https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548011/cannot-install-lxml-on-mac-os-x-10-9

I'll keep trying to figure it out, thanks for your guidance

Comment: @BD I'm afraid I don't no anything about the Mac, but lxml has been around forever, so there shouldn't be an issue. [Try starting from here](https://lxml.de/installation.html).

Comment: I figured out how to run lxml on MacOS 12.2 -- I have to run python2 rather than python3.  Now I get line 134
    exp = f'//xx:g[@id="RoundShapes"]//xx:{target}'
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: And I figured out that the f requires python3.  I can't figure out how to install lxml for python3 on macos 12.2.  Can this code be modified to work with python 2?

Comment: @BD Probably, but I don't have python 2 installed, so I can't test it. Try using `exp = '//xx:g[@id="RoundShapes"]//xx:'+target` instead and see if it works.