# python installing requests-html library fails on mac ("Failed building wheel for lxml")

Tags: python, pip, lxml, python-requests-html

I have created a web scraping project using the requests-html library (in a venv). It was all working well until I stupidly downloaded python again in the normal terminal (instead of the vscode terminal). Since then the code doesn't work anymore and I cannot figure out what the problem is.

So I have opened a new file to test my code iteratively without a venv and I cannot even install the requests-html library at all: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests_html`.
So I run `pip install requests-html` and it gives me the following error:

```
Collecting requests-html
  Using cached requests_html-0.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting pyquery
  Using cached pyquery-1.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting pyppeteer>=0.0.14
  Using cached pyppeteer-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
Collecting bs4
  Using cached bs4-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: w3lib in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests-html) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: parse in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests-html) (1.19.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests-html) (2.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied: fake-useragent in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests-html) (0.1.11)
Collecting importlib-metadata>=1.4
  Using cached importlib_metadata-5.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2021 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pyppeteer>=0.0.14->requests-html) (2022.9.24)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2.0.0,>=1.4.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pyppeteer>=0.0.14->requests-html) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyee<9.0.0,>=8.1.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pyppeteer>=0.0.14->requests-html) (8.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.42.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pyppeteer>=0.0.14->requests-html) (4.64.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<2.0.0,>=1.25.8 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pyppeteer>=0.0.14->requests-html) (1.26.12)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets<11.0,>=10.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pyppeteer>=0.0.14->requests-html) (10.3)
Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (128 kB)
Collecting cssselect>0.7.9
  Using cached cssselect-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting lxml>=2.1
  Using cached lxml-4.9.1.tar.gz (3.4 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests->requests-html) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests->requests-html) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=1.4->pyppeteer>=0.0.14->requests-html) (3.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->bs4->requests-html) (2.3.2.post1)
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [184 lines of output]
      Building lxml version 4.9.1.
      Building without Cython.
      Building against libxml2 2.9.4 and libxslt 1.1.29
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
    
////// I CROPPED THE MESSAGE HERE FOR SPACE REASONS //////
      running build_ext
      building 'lxml.etree' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/src
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/src/lxml
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/src/lxml/etree.o -w -flat_namespace
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:11:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/11.0.3/include/limits.h:21:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:63:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
      #error Unsupported architecture
       ^
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:11:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/11.0.3/include/limits.h:21:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:64:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/limits.h:8:2: error: architecture not supported
      #error architecture not supported
       ^
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
      #error architecture not supported
       ^
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
      typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
              ^
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
      typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
              ^
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
      typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
              ^
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
      typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
              ^
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
      #error architecture not supported
       ^
      fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
      20 errors generated.
      Compile failed: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      creating var
      creating var/folders
      creating var/folders/dz
      creating var/folders/dz/n8vf6x950yjdbzwftt_1vd1m0000gn
      creating var/folders/dz/n8vf6x950yjdbzwftt_1vd1m0000gn/T
      cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /var/folders/dz/n8vf6x950yjdbzwftt_1vd1m0000gn/T/xmlXPathInit046146bm.c -o var/folders/dz/n8vf6x950yjdbzwftt_1vd1m0000gn/T/xmlXPathInit046146bm.o
      cc var/folders/dz/n8vf6x950yjdbzwftt_1vd1m0000gn/T/xmlXPathInit046146bm.o -lxml2 -o a.out
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml, importlib-metadata, cssselect, beautifulsoup4, pyquery, pyppeteer, bs4, requests-html
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for lxml did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [181 lines of output]
      Building lxml version 4.9.1.
      Building without Cython.
      Building against libxml2 2.9.4 and libxslt 1.1.29
      running install
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml



     ////// I CROPPED THE MESSAGE HERE FOR SPACE REASONS //////



      running build_ext
      building 'lxml.etree' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/src
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/src/lxml
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/src/lxml/etree.o -w -flat_namespace
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:11:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/11.0.3/include/limits.h:21:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:63:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
      #error Unsupported architecture
       ^
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:11:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/11.0.3/include/limits.h:21:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:64:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/limits.h:8:2: error: architecture not supported
      #error architecture not supported
       ^
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
      #error architecture not supported
       ^
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
      typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
              ^
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
      typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
              ^
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
      typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
              ^
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
      typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
              ^
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
      #error architecture not supported
       ^
      fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
      20 errors generated.
      Compile failed: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /var/folders/dz/n8vf6x950yjdbzwftt_1vd1m0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitq1lwalnt.c -o var/folders/dz/n8vf6x950yjdbzwftt_1vd1m0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitq1lwalnt.o
      cc var/folders/dz/n8vf6x950yjdbzwftt_1vd1m0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitq1lwalnt.o -lxml2 -o a.out
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Essentially it "fails building the wheel for lxml". How can I solve this issue?
It is weird that everything was running fine until I tinkered with the terminal.
My system is MacOS Monterey V12.5.1

Comment: It's trying to build against headers from MacOS 10.9, which is too old to support M1 hardware.

Comment: ...have you perhaps configured the XCode MinimumSDKVersion setting to let you compile applications for older versions of MacOS? If so, can you change that back?

Comment: I don't think I did.. It all worked perfectly fine a couple of days ago on the same laptop and I don't remember changing anything of that sorts

Comment: Hmm. Do you have XCode installed? If you go to preferences and then the "Locations" tab, does it specify a command line tools version?

Comment: No I don't have XCode installed

Comment: It's a big download, but a good place to start might be installing it; when you run it it'll prompt you to bring the command-line tools up to date. (I'm mostly a Linux developer, so I don't know MacOS as well as some folks here, but the *architecture not supported* error from `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h` is pretty much a smoking gun -- a current version of the MacOSX SDK will support both x86_64 and arm64, whereas older ones will be Intel-only).

Comment: I suspect that when it worked before you were running from downloaded binaries rather than a local build.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot install Lxml on Mac OS X 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548011/cannot-install-lxml-on-mac-os-x-10-9)

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus no I tried all the options, it still gives me the error that lxml couldn't be installed "failed building wheel for lxml"..

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'll try to update the command-line tools and see if that does anything

Comment: How did that go? Even if it still fails after the update, it should be a _different_ failure, one that doesn't include architecture-not-supported issues.

Comment: So it seems to work now, but I can't say what made it happen because (a) I have reinstalled x-code (apparently I did have it on my system before) but I've also (b) downgraded my python version to 3.9.6. and now I can install the requests package as well as run the code successfully. Thank you for your help in any case!