# I am trying to install Scrapy; however, this is the error I am experiencing : Failed building wheel for lxml . Please assist

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, lxml

Experiencing error  Failed building wheel for lxml

src/lxml/etree.c:96:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
#include "Python.h"
^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

ERROR: Could not build wheels for lxml, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

while installing Scrapy

to install Scrapy in Pycharm

Comment: restart your system (computer), update it, then do a `pip install -U scrapy`.

Comment: Hi Barry, Thank you for your response, However, it is still not resolved. To add more information I have a using Mac Ventura 13..4 version. Further, installed PyCharm Community Edition. Now it is showing Error.

 Error: Please make sure the libxml2 and libxslt development packages are installed.

Comment: OK, then do a `pip install -U pip`, then `pip install -U wheel`, then `pip install -U lxml`, then restart your computer. Are you on MacOS by any chance?

Comment: Ok, if you will edit your message previous to my response, we cannot have a conversation. There are known issues with LXML on mac.  See this question, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548011/cannot-install-lxml-on-mac-os-x-10-9

Comment: Thank you Barry. Apologies for the editing. I am new to the Stack Overflow platform and was unaware that clicking return could add the comment. Because I was just wanting to go to the next line. 

Thank you the lxml has been installed with your given response. 

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue recently while installing a package that depends on Scrapy, and I shared what helped me resolve the issue.

The `lxml` package seems to cause such errors when Xcode Command Line Tools are not correctly installed or some paths are missing/broken. As implied in your terminal, first try:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

The command above will install the required packages if not installed already. If you receive the error `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`, try resetting Xcode Command Line Tools as follows. It will reset the path to the Xcode Command Line Tools directory, which may help with the issue.

```
$ sudo xcode-select --reset
```

After you install/update Xcode Command Line Tools, try installing `lxml` separately to see if your issue is resolved.

```
$ pip install lxml
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I simply installed XCode through the App Store (CLI was not sufficient). Seems to have fixed the problem for me!